Pass media library item content to an API
In the XM cloud project, I have a task to update an external DB with media library file content through an API. What is the best way to do this in XM cloud?

I tried to trigger the API call on the Item update event and read
the file stream to send it as a parameter to the API, but I always
got a zero-length stream.
MediaItem file = new MediaItem(item);
var mediaStream = MediaManager.GetMedia(file).GetStream().Stream;
var fileStream = file.GetMediaStream(); //also tried but got zero length stream
if (mediaStream != null)
{
using (var reader = new StreamReader(mediaStream))
{
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
request.AddFile("file", text, file.Name);
}
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}

Another suggestion was to publish the
Item on update, then call API with the public URL, inside the API
we download the file and read its content to trigger the external
DB update, should this approach work in the XM cloud?


Thanks in advance

You should be able to achieve this using a combination of Webhooks and the ItemService.
Create new webhook here /sitecore/system/Webhooks/ called JPG Added

Events: select item_added
Rule: Rule 1: where the item template is jpeg
Enabled: true
Url: some API endpoint you control
Serialisation Type: JSON

More info here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--creating-and-configuring-a-webhook-event-handler.html
In the API that you control, configure the action to receive webhook.
[HttpPost(Name = "WebHookExample")]
public IActionResult WebHookExample(WebhookAction action)
{
    ...
}

Define custom class (bare minimum example below)
public class WebhookAction
{
    public string? EventName { get; set; }
    public SitecoreItem Item { get; set; }
}
public class SitecoreItem
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
}

Normally, you could retrieve the field data (from VersionedFields for example). But in your case, I dont believe blob field types are available. So, I think you would then need to make a call back to Sitecore using the ItemService rest API.
An example of how to do this using .Net can be found here:
https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/sitecore-itemservice-rest-api/
Using this approach, you should then be able to pull out the necessary media information.
Note: this suggestion is based purely on my experience of using Sitecore XP. I havent used XM cloud as yet, so couldnt say for definite... but from my understanding XM cloud is similar to XP CM instance. So the same options should be available. It may be however, that there is a better solution to retrieve the Item data using GraphQL for example.

With XM Cloud you should only use the GraphQL Services.
